# How to pass reactive data to a composable in Vue 3

Tags: typescript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

Is it possible to declare a reactive object in Vue, and then pass members of that object to a composable while retaining reactivity?

For example:

I declare a "State" type:

```
type State = { myObjectList: Array<MyObject> }
```

Then in my component I initialize my state:

```
const state = reactive<State>{( myObjectList: new Array<MyObject>() )}
```

Where `state.myObjectList` gets populated via API call on component mount

My question is, is it possible to pass around `state.myObjectList` to a composable, and have that composable be aware of changes made to elements inside of `state.myObjectList`?

i.e. to have a composable like:

```
export default function useSimpleCalculator(list: Array<MyObject>){

  const dynamicSumValue = computed(():number => { 
    let sum = 0;
    list.forEach(el => {  sum += el.someValueThatChanges });
    return sum;
  });

 return { dynamicSumValue }

}
```

then use that composable like:

```
const {dynamicSumValue} = useSimpleCalculator(state.myObjectList);
```

and have `dynamicSumValue` be updated as changes are made to elements inside `state.myObjectList`

I've tried to implement like the above, but when I pass any property that was on the `state` object, it loses its reactivity inside the composable.

Passing `ref`s to the composable seems to work ( i.e. `const val = ref(2)` ), but that goes against the pattern our team decided on for component-wide state data

Any insight would be helpful

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As you've discovered, you cannot pass properties of a reactive object to a function and maintain reactivity for that property.  This comes up often for props as well, which are just a reactive object like 'state' in your example.  You'll need to convert your state to refs and pass a ref for reactivity to work properly:

```
useSimpleCalculator(toRef(state, 'myObjectList'));
```

or

```
const { myObjectList } = toRefs(state);
useSimpleCalculator(myObjectList)
```

will both work

Comment: first solution was perfect, thanks a bunch

Comment: Also found this answer in the Vue [documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/api/refs-api.html#unref)

Answer (score 4):

Refs are specifically used for cases when a value needs to be passed by reference (hence the name).

Since `list` is not supposed to be modified, it can be just a computed ref:

```
const myObjectList = computed(() => state.myObjectList);
useSimpleCalculator(myObjectList);
```

and

```
function useSimpleCalculator(list: Ref<Array<MyObject>> | ComputedRef<Array<MyObject>>){...}
```

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works, however I like @maembe solution better as it seems cleaner and a little more obvious that I'm converting to a `ref`, and don't need the declaration of the additional `computed`. Appreciate your help!

Comment: They serve different purposes. A computed indicates the intention better because it's not supposed to be modified, unless a setter is provided. It's the same choice as `const` vs `let`. You can use `let` everywhere because it's less to type, or you can use `const` to prevent accidental assignments. You can have your own helpers for your own store if you need to reduce the boilerplate, similarly to Vuex mapGetters.